# Union narrowing breaks after doing a property access

Tags: typescript, unions

I've pared down my code to a minimal reproduction of the problem (see comment section below and edit history). I believe the following code should fail on the line where we try to set `p` to 5 because `T` is 0 so `config` should be `string`.

```js
type testUnion = { config: string, prop: 0 } | { config : number, prop: 1 };
type testGeneric<T extends 0 | 1> = testUnion & { prop: T };
type testProp<T extends 0 | 1> = testGeneric<T>["config"]; //string | number

const p: testProp<0> = 5;
```

Is this a possible bug with TypeScript? Or is there a way to write `testProp` that maintains `testGeneric<0>["config"]` as `string`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7AKoDsCWB7ZUC8UDeUAxpgGaoDmAXFAgE6rLkA0UYt6Y1ADFAL5QAffEVIUo1ZAFcAtgCMItFmw7UAjHwDcAKFCQY8YAHEIyBakIAeACpQIAD1jIAJnCg8hqgHw59CFBiwAMmFlTigbXm1daFgEAAV2MGtbBxMXN0EoLx9YoxMzSytPAG0AImJkMnJSgF0NKAB6BroGckypOQUtLQqEVmpchI4LLm9cAFYNIA)

Comment: Why so convoluted? :) You can redefine the types [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Wvp6nN) and be done with it. As for the problem itself, I am not sure how eagerly generics are resolved with regards to indexed access, but it seems `SpecificConfig<Kind>['config']` is resolved as if `Kinds` was passed instead of a subtype of `Kinds`

Comment: @OlegValter in the real problem, there are far more than 2 kinds, so that ternary would become very long and hard to follow. I don't really think these types are more convoluted than your solution either, to be honest.

Comment: First of all, this is a joke. Secondly, the question did not indicate there are more than 2. When there are 2 types, conditional types are an easy solution. Finally, if you have multiple configs and worry about maintainability, how about a solution with a map-based? https://tsplay.dev/N5E6BN

Comment: Yes, I tried to pare down the problem as much as I could while still preserving the point. I still think this might be a bug with TypeScript, so I'm coming at this less from a "how do I work around this?" and more of a "why is this giving an error?". As you note, it's resolved as if `Kinds` is passed even when `Kind` is passed, but that seems like bad behavior on TypeScript's part, right?

Comment: That's true, that's why that's just a comment and not an answer - I am unsure if that's "bad behavior" or a reasonable tradeoff - when you access a property on a generic it does make sense to resolve it as soon as possible to check if the resulting type can be indexed by the property (`config` in your case), and the only info given at that point is that `Kind` is at least of type `Kinds`. Not saying that it definitely does work that way, but it seems to be the case. Dried down version: https://tsplay.dev/mZ8now

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely true -- if that were the case, wouldn't `inner` in the outer scope fail? It seems like a specific problem with subclassing. I had to keep the class structure (`Configurable`/`ClassA`) in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm incorrect there. It is reproducible but TypeScript was doing an eager narrowing in my original example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBBKBeKBvAKCmKjACc5IzQMAuKAZ2DJQTQG4CBfAg0SWIlRoAQjnxES5ShGogR9JizacefcNAAqAQzRoIAE3jJ04gBSESUANasD9AOTaHAGm5QAZPigBjIenpjYSwuAEooAB8oC0liWwR7KAcAI1d3LzxffzRA7LEwznUBAGk7BnEdPUMg9ABtB3iDBwBdQv5oAGVIHxRUHxq0AB5ShKgIAA9gCATykYMGAD4K3X0jbM9vRvo5qB52qABJBARZAeG7Mcnp+ag5xfEuiB6+s7mF+r8TNBbeT6YobT0R7PFD9bKDJwOJa4TJbJLOFxZL70TLSKg0RzaZy7LicP5wAA2EAAdAS4GgzNpiZ9hMS0bIaKE8Yh-qwTmR6Ed2WdIdDvPS5AokslUrsCPiiaTyWY2bI6RR0fImUA

Comment: Actually your example is even easier, though I modified it to actually show something that shouldn't work to illustrate what is unexpected. See the question for the version I'm now using to show the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, that's why I condensed it to a barebones sample. I think this is a normal-ish behavior, but can't find any clarifications on that yet.  `type t3 = testUnion & { prop: 0|1 };` is unresolved, so when you access the `config` property, the union distribution results in the property being returned as a union of types of its values. Seems more like a trade-off to me, or one would have to resolve `testUnion & { prop: T }`, which is undesirable since `T` is not substituted yet.